# Trying to display a gif in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following to show the gif but it stops the rest of the script running.

If i change to $form.show() it runs the rest of the script but the gif dosent work

Any ideas?

```
   [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$file = (get-item "666.gif")

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($file);

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
$form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
$form.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$form.TopMost = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = $none;
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
$pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$pictureBox.Image = $img;
$form.controls.add($pictureBox)
$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: `FromFile($file)` -> `FromFile($file.FullName)`. If that doesn't help, please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work" - do you get errors? If not, what's the behavior your seeing (or not seeing)?

Comment: The gif shows and works when using the above but it stops the rest of the script intill its closed

Comment: It's a bit tricky to advice not knowing what you are trying to accomplish. However, you might wanna give `$form.Show()` a try instead of `$form.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Also, unless you give the variable `$none` a value earlier in the script somewhere I'd imagine `$form.FormBorderStyle = $none` would throw an exception. `$form.FormBorderStyle = 0` should equal to `none' in this case anywho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Show and set correctly the borderstyle property.

Try this:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile("666.gif");

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
$form = new-object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
$form.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$form.TopMost = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::None;
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBox.Width =  $img.Size.Width;
$pictureBox.Height =  $img.Size.Height;
$pictureBox.Image = $img;
$form.controls.add($pictureBox)
$form.Add_Shown( { $form.Activate() } )
$form.Show()

1..20 | %{"Continue program {0}" -f $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

By running the script in another runspace, you will get the behavior you expect.

```
# Create runspace
$runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$runspace.Open()

# Add script and run asynchronously
$runspace.CreatePipeline{

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $image = [Drawing.Bitmap]"C:\sample.gif"

    $pictureBox = [Windows.Forms.PictureBox]@{ Dock = "Fill"; Image = $image }
    $form = [Windows.Forms.Form]@{ Size = $image.Size; FormBorderStyle = "None" }
    $form.Controls.Add($pictureBox)

    $form.ShowDialog()

}.InvokeAsync()
```